# Why I my array prints large numbers even though i am scanning the small numbers in C language

Tags: arrays, c

i am trying to print the array with no duplicate numbers inside that, for that i have to take 20 numbers from users between the range of 10 and 100. There is a condition that i have to use only one array to solve this problem.

Problem is when I am trying to enter the number such as 99, 98 etc the array prints those numbers but it also prints the large random numbers i don't know what problem is there in my code. Can anyone help me with this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX 20

void main(){

   int number_array[MAX]; //the only array which will store the non repitative value
   int i,j,k=0,duplicate;
   long value; //having duplicate which will catch the duplicate value
   
   printf("Enter 20 numbers between 10 and 100: \n");
   
   //read the numbers from using the for loop
   for(i=0; i < MAX - 1; i++){
      duplicate = 0;
      scanf("%ld",&value);
      
      if(value <= 10 || value >= 100) { //if value not lies in range ask again to read the input
         printf("Please enter the value between 10 and 100\n");
         i--;    
      }
      
      for(j = 0; j < k; j++){ //checks whether the read value already stored in array
         if(value == number_array[j]){ // if yes break the loop
            duplicate = 1;
            break;         
         }
      }
      
      if(!duplicate && (value > 10 && value < 100)){ //this conditio checks the range and duplicacy if yes do not stored in array
         number_array[k++] = value;      
      }
      
   }
   
   printf("The Array with no repitive integers are: \n");
   printf("[");
   for(i = 0; i < sizeof(number_array); i++){
      if(i == sizeof(number_array) - 1){
         printf("%d ", number_array[i]);
      }else {
      printf("%d, ", number_array[i]);}
   }
   printf("]");}
```

Here is the output:

```
Enter 20 numbers between 10 and 100: 
21
23
24
25
26
27
8
Please enter the value between 10 and 100
29
28
28
98
97
96
95
94
92
89
78
54
45
The Array with no repitive integers are: 
[21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 29, 28, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 92, 89, 78, 54, 45, 6422352, 4201163, 0, 18, 17, 23, 6422284, 3584000, 6422352, 4199048, 1, 12201480, 12197232, 2, 0, 6422352, 2002089485, 3584000, 6422400, 4199157, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2004247385, 3584000, 2004247360, 6422492, 2011597124, 3584000, 811369607, 0, 0, 3584000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6422412, 0, 6422500, 2011672880, 1204624915, 0, 6422508, 2011597076, -1, 2011734250, 0, 0, 4199136, 3584000, 0 ]
 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 93.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Comment: `sizeof` returns a literal size in bytes, so unless your elements are a byte long, that will be off by a factor of 2x or more.

Comment: OT: `MAX - 1` why?

Answer (score 2):

```
   for(i = 0; i < sizeof(number_array); i++){
```

You don't care how many characters `number_array` takes up in memory. So don't use `sizeof`. You care how many entries are in the array. That's stored in `k`. So change `sizeof(number_array)` to `k`.